# How do I find the maximum phonetic and synctactic similarity between two strings?

Tags: python, phonetics

I have two strings (e.x "Sacred Heart" and "Sacred Heart Mountain"). Let's call them s1 and s2. S1 and s2 are obviously phonetically similar, but I have no idea how to prove this algorithmically. I'm using levenshtein distance for my similarity metric, as well as Nysiis and Match Rating Codex (MRC) embeddings for phonetic compression. So far, these are working well, except in these cases where one string is significantly longer than the other but contains some substring which is highly similar. Ideally, this algorithm would be in linear time O(n) or less.

The longer the similarity between the substrings the stronger the score. I tried splitting the two strings into substrings separated by spaces, and then comparing all possible combinations against each other. First of all, this algorithm was way too slow, and due to my evaluation metric, shorter substrings tended to do better against each other. After looking online, there hasn't been a similar problem, so I am unsure if this problem can be solved algorithmically.

Comment: You could use Longest Common Substring, and compare the length of the match to the length of the shortest string.

Comment: That works sometimes, but when the strings are not synctactically similar, such as "Nike" and "Nykee", they still possess some phonetic similarity that I wish to evaluate even if they don't have a significant Longest Common Substring.

Comment: One idea would be to convert to phonemes before this comparison. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61987652/530160), but unfortunately, it only has pronunciations for things that are in the dictionary. For a word like Nykee, it can't figure out what it sounds like.